# Converting C# line to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I was trying to convert the following c# code to vb.net.
I see the problem is my lack of familiarity with the syntax of the parameters of OrderByDescending() What is the proper VB.Net equivalent of the C# line?

```
//C# code
SelectedFolder.Search("ALL", true).OrderByDescending(_ => _.Date).ToList();

//VB.Net part which doesn't work
For Each msg In SelectedFolder.Search("ALL", True).OrderByDescending(Function(_).[Date]).ToList()
```

After removing the underscore before [Date] the error became,

> Error 1   Identifier expected.

Comment: An underscore is an odd variable name choice

Comment: The error message says "Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error."  Have you tried specifying the data type(s) explicitly?

Comment: @Brad In this case, yes. But it is commonly used if you *don't* actually use the variable, e.g. `MyList.Find(_ => true)` (which is equivalent to `MyList.FirstOrDefault()`, but works in .NET 2.0).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `_` character is a line continuation in VB.  Try changing the variable name to something more common, like `x`

```
For Each msg In SelectedFolder.Search("ALL", True).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.[Date]).ToList()
```

Comment: I thought that " _" (space followed by underscore) was the line continuation token, and only if it occurs at the very end of a line?  The sequence " _" mid-line *shouldn't* cause any problems.  I would expect syntax errors if the parser was being tripped up on this, not argument type mismatch errors.

Comment: @cdhowie: From MSDN "If an identifier begins with an underscore, it must contain at least one other valid identifier character to disambiguate it from a line continuation." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711644(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Meta-Knight Interesting.  I wonder if this changed since the days of VB6, since I seem to recall this working in VB6.  Shrug.